# I want to replace carriage returns with commas in batch

Tags: file, batch-file, text, replace

I have a text file called test.txt that has sections called `PROP-VALUES`. using batch, I want to replace every other carriage return with commas, but only in the `PROP-VALUES` sections. Attached are the original file test.txt and the fixed file test fixed.txt

Original

[image: original]

Fixed

[image: fixed]

Comment: This is... not easy in batch (it's not impossible, but it's not easy). Also please add any code you have written to your question. If you have not written any code, please do so and add it to your question.

Comment: Just read the file until PROP-VALUES section start and then combine values until the section end. However, you must know that a Batch file can NOT process a .jpg image, like the one you posted...

Comment: Did you... just seriously post screenshots of text files??

Comment: Do you really mean carriage-returns, or are you actually talking about Windows-style line-breaks, which consist of a carriage-return followed by a line-feed? And please copy the text into the question directly (properly [formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))!

Comment: I posted screenshots of text files because I couldn't make the question look right...if I could do it in Perl it would have been easy...I haven't written code because I'm not very knowledgeable of batch commands

Comment: You probably should have read the forum tour before posting then.

Comment: This is perfect, except I need the output to replace the original file (or create a new one).

Comment: please copy the input and output texts and paste here. Not in images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see "questions" like this one (with no good specifications nor code, not even a couple example text lines!) I consider that I can write whatever code I want, so I couldn't resist the temptation to try a crazy method!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set LF=^
%Don't remove%
%these lines%
set "EOL=!LF!" & set "EOL2=!LF!"

for /F %%a in (test.txt) do (
   if %%a equ PROP-SUMMARY set "EOL=!LF!"
   set /P "=%%a!EOL!" < NUL
   set "EOL0=!EOL!" & set "EOL=!EOL2!" & set "EOL2=!EOL0!"
   if %%a equ PROP-VALUES set "EOL=,"
)
```

This is **test.txt**:

```
4.12
0
1
1
21
PROP-VALUES
625
4.12
945
3.64
PROP-SUMMARY
400
400
Thickness
```

This is the output:

```
4.12
0
1
1
21
PROP-VALUES
625,4.12
945,3.64
PROP-SUMMARY
400
400
Thickness
```

Comment: The crazy method that I was envisioning involved `certutil -encodehex` and then changing `0d 0a` to `2c`.

Comment: This is perfect, except I need to modify the original file with the output of the script.