# Modify multiple files with spaces in the filenames in batch

Tags: batch-file, filenames, spaces

I have a directory **c:\test** that is populated automatically with files named **PM1 2016-10-06 1.AL1, PM1 2016-10-06 2.AL1, PM1 2016-10-07 1.AL1** etc.  I have written (thanks to **Aacini** for the core code!) a batch script that works exactly the way I need it to, but my problem is that it only works on one file, and the file cannot have spaces in the filename. The code:

```
@echo off

cd c:\test

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set LF=^

%do not remove%
%these lines%

set "EOL=!LF!" & set "EOL2=!LF!"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\test\PM1.AL1) do (
     if %%a equ PROP-SUMMARY set "EOL=!LF!"
     set /P "=%%a!EOL!" < NUL
     set "EOL0=!EOL!" & set "EOL=!EOL2!" & set "EOL2=!EOL0!"
     if %%a equ PROP-VALUES set "EOL=,"
  ) >>c:\test\test.tmp
TYPE c:\test\test.tmp | FIND "" /V > c:\test\PM1_new.AL1"

DEL c:\test\test.tmp
```

If you're curious about the TYPE line, it changes all the CRs in the file to CRLFs.

Comment: Your title states that you need it to work on multiple files, but how would you determine which files? Do you need it to work on all files in the directory?

Comment: all files in the directory

Comment: I do not read any information telling me what specifically needs to be modified. Usually helps to provide input and **output** examples.

Comment: this script works for one file, PM1.AL1. I need it to work on PM1 2016-10-07 1.AL1 and PM1 2016-10-06 2.AL1 etc.  I thought I was pretty clear, i.e., I need a for loop for the filenames, and it needs to be able to handle spaces in the filenames?

Comment: It is convenient that you include a [link to the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798675/i-want-to-replace-carriage-returns-with-commas-in-batch), so other users can review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd c:\test

set LF=^
%do not remove%
%these lines%

for %%f in (*.*) do (

   set "EOL=!LF!" & set "EOL2=!LF!"

   (for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%%f") do (
      if %%a equ PROP-SUMMARY set "EOL=!LF!"
      set /P "=%%a!EOL!"
      set "EOL0=!EOL!" & set "EOL=!EOL2!" & set "EOL2=!EOL0!"
      if %%a equ PROP-VALUES set "EOL=,"
   )) < NUL > test.tmp

   TYPE test.tmp | FIND "" /V > "%%f"

)

DEL test.tmp
```

Comment: That is perfect my friend. Your mastery of the Windows command line is enviable. The only change I made is I moved DEL test.tmp above the last parentheses. Thank you!

Comment: Does this rename the files?

Comment: yes, check out the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798675/i-want-to-replace-carriage-returns-with-commas-in-batch

Comment: If you move the `DEL test.tmp` command inside the `for`, the file is deleted several times, but this is not necessary because the `> test.tmp` redirection also delete the file before insert the redirected data...